# Remove session index php

Tags: php

**New to php**

I want to remove index with value from php session array. I'm using this code

```
$max=count($_SESSION['Item']);

for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){

 if(strpos($_SESSION['Item'][$i]['Name'],'Shipping')!== false)
 {
  unset($_SESSION['Item'][$i]);
  break;
 }
```

its working fine if value exists in last index of array. But if it exists in between. it doesn't work at all. Where am i going wrong?

Comment: $_SESSION['Item'][$i] = '';

Comment: @tinyByte: How does that help? OP: Will there always be at most one entry you want to remove or might there be more than one?

Comment: @TheWolf multiple entry. but its removing only last value/index pair

Comment: I don't think you need the `break`, that'll exit the loop when a match is found

Comment: The `break;` will cause your `for` loop to stop as soon as the first match is found. Remove that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [array_splice](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php), to remove items

```
array_splice($_SESSION['Item'], $i, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the `foreach` instead of `for`. This way your array keys can be more then only int. And is guaranteed to loop over all the array items

```
foreach($_SESSION['Item'] as $key => $value) { 
    if (strpos($value['Name'],'Shipping')!== false) {
        unset($_SESSION['Item'][$key]);
    }
}
```

As pointed out the break will stop the loop. So if you only want to remove a single entry, you should add the break

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(strpos($_SESSION['Item'][$i]['Name'],'Shipping')!== false)
 {
  unset($_SESSION['Item'][$i]);
 }
```